# Modifing CheckAccessCore(ctx) to permit WCF Help pages w/o authentication

Tags: wcf, security, authentication, token, httpcontext

I need to apply a different set of security policies to the "Help" urls on a WCF service.  How can I get the full URL of the WCF service.. namely `Session` or `Session.svc`?

```
http://localhost:62302/Session.svc/help
http://localhost:62302/Session.svc/help/operations/GetSession
http://localhost:62302/Session/help
http://localhost:62302/Session/help/operations/GetSession
```

Since this is security-related, I need to vet anything I come up with against the community.  [The author here suggests](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1d767d9-d6bf-41ee-89a8-313d338e63b6/) that I simply check if the string ends in "help" and then blindly permit that query (which is obviously incorrect)

**Code snip**

```
public class APIKeyAuthorization : ServiceAuthorizationManager
{
     protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        if (this.IsHelpPage(operationContext.RequestContext.RequestMessage) || IsValidAPIKey(operationContext))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            string key = GetAPIKey(operationContext);

            // Send back an HTML reply
            CreateErrorReply(operationContext, key);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private bool IsHelpPage(Message requestMessage)
    {
        return requestMessage.Headers.To.AbsolutePath.ToLower().EndsWith("help");
    }
 }
```

[full source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2010/06/14/how-to-do-api-key-verification-for-rest-services-in-net-4.aspx)

Comment: "The author here suggests that I simply check if the string ends in "help" and then blindly permit that query (which is obviously incorrect)".  Yeah, because `http://example.com/extremely-sensitive-page?now-i-pwn-you=help` should be exempt from the security policy.

Comment: Just to clarify for the uninitiated... Mike is being sarcastic  ;)

Answer (score 0):

This may be over-simplifying your original question but why not put the help section in its own unprotected area? You can create a Help controller who's sole purpose is to serve up help pages. You will then need to configure your web.config to allow users to access the help section with no authentication. Again this may be over-simplifying it but it's worth a shot.